# HTML scraping using YQL

Tags: web-scraping, yql

I am trying to use YQL to scrape some websites. When I test various queries in the YQL console I get an results node. So for example when I run:

```
select * from html where url="http://www.reverbnation.com/" and xpath='/html/body'
```

I get an empty `<results />` node ([permalink](http://y.ahoo.it/IuZ+Scvs)).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.reverbnation.com may be blocking the request coming from Yahoo! based on certain criteria, like headers. I had a look at reverbnation's robots.txt, and they aren't blocking Yahoo! based on the "Yahoo Pipes 2.0" user agent, so it must be something else.

To re-create the issue, make a YQL query against your own site, then look at the full access logs to see the full request and all headers that came from Yahoo! Then make a similar request using a tool like [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/).

You can also try and run netcat on a port and query with http://yoursite.com:PORT to see the full request.

Related issue [discussed here](http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/?showtopic=2228&endsession=1).

Comment: Any idea how to scrape image and meta description from http://www.amazon.in/Xiaomi-Redmi-4A-Grey-16GB/dp/B01FM7K078?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=87MVWA5E1E8PEBZE8XZN&ref_=nav_custrec_signin&ref_=pd_rhf_gw_p_img_1 ?